# Positioning below non fixed element

Tags: html, css

So I have created an a div called  which I have sized by a height percentage. I'm wanting to position something 25 pixels below it. Since this item isn't a fixed height I'm not sure how to do this. If this is confusing I have also have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2yfxmgu6/). In case you are still confused I'm trying to get the text in the div THISONE to show 25px below.

HTML:

```
<div id="absoluteDiv"></div>
<div id="THISONE">
 I WANT THIS TO SHOW 25px Below the "absoluteDiv"    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#absoluteDiv  {
    background-color:#0F0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:45%;
}

#THISONE {
}
```

Comment: See the first part of my answer for a non-absolute-positioning method.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
#THISONE {    
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(45% + 25px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/05Lrdhu5/

Comment: Is there a way to do this without positioning it as absolute?

Comment: @Jace unfortunately I'm on mobile right now so some things display funny. I can take a look later

Comment: @Jace I cannot figure out a way to do that unless you make them both relative: http://jsfiddle.net/v18ar8gy/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to make it a child of a relative child of the absolute div.

```
<div id="absoluteDiv">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="THISONE">
         I WANT THIS TO SHOW 25px Below the "absoluteDiv"    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#container
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#THISONE {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yfxmgu6/1/)

---

#### Pending:

> Something's up with this one. Let me look into it a bit more.

<strike>One solution would be to simply use padding and calc, if the conditions are exact:</strike>

```
#THISONE {    
    padding-top: calc(45% + 25px);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yfxmgu6/2/)

Comment: The first one didn't seem to work correctly, might want to check that one again.

Comment: @Jace hmm after resizing the window, I see your point. I'll have to troubleshoot that one. In the meantime, the second method does work properly.

Comment: Would it maybe even be possible to do something in javascript to fix this? I'm not very good in javascript otherwise I would try to make something to fix it myself

Comment: @Jace It is possible to use js to move elements around, but it's more lightweight to do with CSS opposed to listen to `resize` and `scroll`.